# Generating interactive partial dependence plots in R using loop extremely slow

Tags: r, ggplot2, partial, ggplotly

I'm trying to generate interactive partial dependence plots by looping over the columns in the data set.

A reproducible example:

```
library(pdp)
library(xgboost)
library(Matrix)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

data(mtcars)
target <- mtcars$mpg
mtcars$mpg <- NULL

mtcars.sparse <- sparse.model.matrix(target~., mtcars)

fit <- xgboost(data=mtcars.sparse, label=target, nrounds=100)

for (i in seq_along(names(mtcars))){
  p1 <- pdp::partial(fit,
                     pred.var = names(mtcars)[i],
                     pred.grid = data.frame(unique(mtcars[names(mtcars)[i]])),
                     train = mtcars.sparse,
                     type = "regression",
                     cats = c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"),
                     plot = FALSE)
  p2 <- ggplot(aes_string(x = names(mtcars)[i] , y = "yhat"), data = p1) +
    geom_line(color = '#E51837', size = .6) +
    labs(title = paste("Partial Dependence plot of", names(mtcars)[i] , sep = " ")) +
    theme(text = element_text(color = "#444444", family = 'Helvetica Neue'),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 13, color = '#333333'))

  print(ggplotly(p2, tooltip = c("x", "y")))

}
```

The plotting loop on my real data set (~22k rows, 30 columns) takes around 2 hours. Any ideas on how to speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way data structures are used in R, `for()` loops can be excruciatingly slow if you're not careful. If you want to know more about the technical reasons behind this, take a look at [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/) by Hadley Wickham.

Practically, there are two main approaches to speeding up what you're looking to do: optimizing the `for()` loop, and using the `apply()` family of functions. While both approaches can work well, the `apply()` method tends to be faster, even than an optimally written `for()` loop, so I'll stick with that solution.

the `apply` method:

```
plotFunction <- 
  function(x) {
    p1 <- pdp::partial(fit,
                       pred.var = x,
                       pred.grid = data.frame(unique(mtcars[x])),
                       train = mtcars.sparse,
                       type = "regression",
                       cats = c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"),
                       plot = FALSE)
    p2 <- ggplot(aes_string(x = x , y = "yhat"), data = p1) +
      geom_line(color = '#E51837', size = .6) +
      labs(title = paste("Partial Dependence plot of", x , sep = " ")) +
      theme(text = element_text(color = "#444444", family = 'Helvetica Neue'),
            plot.title = element_text(size = 13, color = '#333333'))
    return(p2)
  }


plot.list <- lapply(varNames, plotFunction)

system.time(lapply(varNames, plotFunction))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.471   0.004   0.488
```

Running the same benchmark on your `for()` loop gave:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  3.945   0.616   3.519
```

As you'll notice, that's about a 10X improvement in speed, simply by pasting your loop code into a function, with minor modifications.

If you want additional speed, there are a few tweaks you can make to your function, but perhaps the most powerful aspect of the `apply()` approach is that it lends itself well to parallelization, which can be done with packages like `pbmcapply`

implementing `pbmcapply` gives you even more speed;

```
library(pdp)
library(xgboost)
library(Matrix)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(pbmcapply)

# Determines the number of cores you want to use for paralell processing
# I like to leave two of mine available, but you can get away with 1
nCores <-  detectCores() - 1

data(mtcars)
target <- mtcars$mpg
mtcars$mpg <- NULL

mtcars.sparse <- sparse.model.matrix(target~., mtcars)

fit <- xgboost(data=mtcars.sparse, label=target, nrounds=100)

varNames <- 
  names(mtcars) %>%
  as.list

plotFunction <- 
  function(x) {
    p1 <- pdp::partial(fit,
                       pred.var = x,
                       pred.grid = data.frame(unique(mtcars[x])),
                       train = mtcars.sparse,
                       type = "regression",
                       cats = c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"),
                       plot = FALSE)
    p2 <- ggplot(aes_string(x = x , y = "yhat"), data = p1) +
      geom_line(color = '#E51837', size = .6) +
      labs(title = paste("Partial Dependence plot of", x , sep = " ")) +
      theme(text = element_text(color = "#444444", family = 'Helvetica Neue'),
            plot.title = element_text(size = 13, color = '#333333'))
    return(p2)
  }


plot.list <- pbmclapply(varNames, plotFunction, mc.cores = nCores)
```

Let's see how that did

```
   user  system elapsed 
  0.842   0.458   0.320
```

A small improvement over `lapply()`, but that improvement should scale with your bigger dataset. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Debbie, did this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry for the super late reply. I ended up using the first option. Thanks so much.